# Static html/css/javascript front end connected to WordPress

Tags: front-end, static-website

I heard of an option to build websites by creating a static html/css/javascript front end and connecting that to a WordPress admin side or even an excel spreadsheet where the admin add content.

I think this would be amazing but I don't know anything about it yet. I first thought it was something new from WordPress 4.0, but I don't even think it's related to 4.0 because I heard that can be done even with Drupal admin.

So essentially you log in and put the content in Drupal or WordPress but the front end is not a Drupal or WordPress theme. It's just a static site in which the content is fed.

Does anybody knows something about this? Any place to look for where they talk about it or explain it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to take advantage of content from within Wordpress that doesn't use its templating system, one means of doing so would be the [Ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).  Your client-side code would call Wordpress Ajax functions that would return the content you desire.

As to the spreadsheet matter, this is not standard Wordpress behavior, but you can [find various plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=csv+import) that will allow you to import .CSV files (which can be exported from within Excel) as content.  I am doubtful that you will find plugins that can read the native Excel format, but could be mistaken.